# How can I alert the inner HTML of a HTML tag <td> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
function loadme(){
    var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
    rows = tbl.document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    cells = tbl.rows.getElementsByTagName("td");
    alert(rows[7].cells[6].innerHTML);
}
```

TypeError: Cannot read property `'getElementsByTagName'` of undefined

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pease do not edit the question with corrected codes, for new users, question and answer doesnt make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
 rows = tbl.document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

If you look close you are trying to access `document` object of `tb1` which doesnt exist at all

try

```
 rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

**Update :**

```
cells = tbl.rows.getElementsByTagName("td");
```

should be

```
cells = rows[index].getElementsByTagName("td");
```

Comment: TypeError: rows.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Comment: i had another error
TypeError: rows.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Comment: @MiiNii - That's because `rows` is a list, not a single element.

Comment: Ahh my bad, edited my answer. you need to add an index to get elements inside a single row. @nnnnnn Thanks for the spot. Advanced 100k wishes :)

Comment: Thanks. Not long to go! Note that you can also just use the `.rows` and `.cells` collections instead of calling `.getElementsByTagName`, that is: `tbl.rows[7].cells[6]`.

Comment: @nnnnnn true. OP can still use the syntax if he want to iterate over all the cells :)

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it

```
function loadme(){
    var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
        rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        cells = tbl.getElementsByTagName("td");

    alert(rows[2].cells[1].innerHTML);
}
```